# Python: want to catch exception, but don't know where it comes from?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Python using the Django tutorial, and I have this code

```
poll = Poll.objects.get(pk = poll_id)
```

When poll_id is not in the database I get a DoesNotExist exception, which is fine because the tutorial tells me to do the following:

```
try:
    poll = Poll.objects.get(pk = poll_id)
except Poll.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

My question is: if I didn't have the tutorial to help me, how would I, given the stack trace below, have known that the DoesNotExist exception is part of Poll?

(i.e. my guess would have been to put 'except DoesNotExist:' and this would have told me: "global name 'DoesNotExist' is not defined")

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/tom/Documents/dev/django-test/mysite/polls/views.py" in detail
  26.   poll = Poll.objects.get(pk = poll_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  307.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /polls/3/
Exception Value: Poll matching query does not exist.
```

Totally new to python.  I'm obviously missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't have known; you'd have to look at the [project documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/) or the code throwing the exception.

Note that the `Model.DoesNotExist` reference is a convenience so you don't have to import the exception either. You wouldn't deduce this from the code throwing the exception. This special Django exception object is a subclass of [`django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist) customized per model.

In general, you could catch `Exception` and look at the module of the exception caught:

```
except Exception as e:
    print type(e), type(e).__module__
```

This would tell you what module the exception is defined in, giving you the option to import it from there in future.